# Can't run tests from Espresso Test Recorder

Tags: android, android-espresso

I used the test recorder to create a simple UI Test. However when I run the test that was generated, I get an error

```
Error:(4, 37) error: package android.support.test.espresso does not exist
Error:(5, 33) error: package android.support.test.rule does not exist
Error:(6, 35) error: package android.support.test.runner does not exist
Error:(14, 20) error: package org.hamcrest does not exist
Error:(15, 20) error: package org.hamcrest does not exist
Error:(16, 20) error: package org.hamcrest does not exist
Error:(17, 25) error: package org.hamcrest.core does not exist
Error:(18, 17) error: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(19, 17) error: package org.junit does not exist
Error:(20, 24) error: package org.junit.runner does not exist
Error:(22, 44) error: package android.support.test.espresso does not exist
Error:(22, 1) error: static import only from classes and interfaces
Error:(23, 51) error: package android.support.test.espresso.action does not exist
Error:(23, 1) error: static import only from classes and interfaces
```

You get the idea. I don't see any warnings or errors in Android Studio until I try to run the test.

Does anyone have an idea of what may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add forget add espresso to your dependencies ?

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon further inspection, similar issue found here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=98326

Their solution didn't work for me. Turns out that I head to exclude the test package from the java sourceset in the build.gradle.

```
sourceSets{
  main {
    java.srcDirs = ['src']
    java.excludes = ['instrumentTest/**','test/**']
    ...
  }
}
```